# One variable inequality problem $\frac{x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}}{x^2 - 4} - 1 > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

Hi I'm having problem with inequality

$\frac{x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}}{x^2 - 4} - 1 > 0$

I rearranged the equation a bit and I did this

$\frac{x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}-x^2+4}{x^2 - 4}  > 0$ holds if

$(x-2) \cdot(x+2)\cdot (x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}-x^2+4)>0$

This part is the most difficult for me
$(x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}-x^2+4) = 0$

I am unable to find solution of this equation  and I think this is crucial to solving it.
I also tried other ways to solve this equation, such as moving 1 to the other side of the equation. And then I multiply both sides by $(x-2)^2 \cdot (x+2)^2$ But I also failed because I probably at some point illegally raised both sides to the second power.

I also have answer for that inequality:
$x\in(-2,\sqrt{2})\cup(2, \infty)$

I also tried to calculating this equation using programs such as wolfram alpha but only gives me a result and I would like to know how I could solve it.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Apparent typo in your *official solution*, should be $~x \in (-2, -\sqrt{2}) \cup (2,\infty).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\dfrac{x\sqrt{|x^2 - 4|}}{x^2 - 4} - 1 > 0$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~~x^2 - 4 > 0}$

$$\frac{x\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{x^2 - 4} > 1 \implies $$

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}} > 1 \implies $$

$$x > \sqrt{x^2 - 4} > 0 \implies $$

$$x^2 > x^2 - 4.$$

So, candidates for Case 1, are any $~x > 2.~$

You can manually verify that any $~x > 2~$ satisfies the original inequality.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~~x^2 - 4 < 0}$

$$\frac{x\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{x^2 - 4} > 1 \implies $$

$$\frac{x\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{4 - x^2} < -1 \implies $$

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}} < -1 \implies $$

$$x < -\sqrt{4 - x^2} < 0 \implies $$

$$x^2 > 4 - x^2 \implies $$

$$2x^2 > 4 \implies x^2 > 2.$$

So, the Case 2 candidate values are $~\displaystyle -2 < x < -\sqrt{2}.$

Since the Case 2 candidate values each imply that $~x^2 > 4 - x^2,~$ you can manually verify that each of the Case 2 candidate values satisfy the original inequality.

---

$\underline{\text{Final Results}}$

Satisfying values are $~x > 2~$ or $~\displaystyle -2 < x < -\sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

First case: $\;x^2-4<0\iff (x-2)(x+2)<0\iff -2<x<2\;$ , and then your inequality becomes

$$\frac{x\sqrt{-x^2+4}}{x^2-4}-1>0\iff x\sqrt{-x^2+4}-x^2+4<0 (**)$$

Last inequality due to the fact that we multiplied through by $\;x^2-4<0\;$

and now:

$$x\sqrt{-x^2+4}<x^2-4$$

and since the expression in the square root is always non negative and the right side is negative, it must be that $\;-2<x<0\;$ . In order to have two positive sides divide through by $\;x<0\;$ and :

$$\sqrt{-x^2+4}>x-\frac4x\implies-x^2+4>\left(x-\frac4x\right)^2=x^2-8+\frac{16}{x^2}\implies$$

$$2x^4-12x^2+16<0\Longleftrightarrow x^4-6x^2+8<0\Longleftrightarrow(x^2-2)(x^2-4)<0\Longrightarrow...$$

and take it from here, without forgetting what range $\;x\;$ is in.

Then do something similar for $\;x^2-4\ge0\Longleftrightarrow x\le-2\;\;or\;\;x\ge2\;$ ....

Answer (score 1):

As a hint: Divide into two part $x \in (-2,2)$ , $x \not\in(-2,2)$
for the first one $$x \in(-2,2) \to x^2-4<0  \\ \frac{x\sqrt{|4-x^2|}}{x^2 - 4} >1\\ \frac{x\sqrt{4-x^2}}{-(4-x^2)}>1\\ \frac{x\sqrt{(4-x^2)}}{-\sqrt{(4-x^2)^2}}>1\\
\frac{x}{-\sqrt{(4-x^2)^1}}>1$$ and for the second
$$x \not \in(-2,2) \to x^2-4>0  \\\frac{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2 - 4} >1\\
\frac{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{(x^2 - 4)^2}} >1\\\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}} >1\\$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do questions like this is to consider "critical values". Imagine if you were solving an equality rather than an inequality, and then consider other behaviour.

So solve $ x\sqrt(|x^2-4|)= x^2-4$

so $ x^2(|x^2-4|)=|x^2-4|^2   $

so $|x^2-4|(x^2-|x^2-4|)=0$

You find that the solutions to this equation are 2,-2 $ \sqrt(2), -\sqrt(2)$

Now, we should sub in these critical points to make sure they make sense (we might get extra solutions):

2 and -2 are undefined asymptotes.
sqrt(2) does not give the right value(-2)
and sqrt(2) does give the right value (0)

At 2 and -2 we have asymptotes:
The asymptote at 2 is clearly towards - infinity from the left, and + infinity from the right.
The same for -2 in fact!
And the curve crosses the axes at -sqrt(2).

Therefore, in conjunction with this information, we can say that $(-2,-\sqrt(2)), (2,\infty)$ are the intervals required.